# How to convert something like 'U+3421' to '你' in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode

How do you go about converting things like 'U+3421' to '你'? Using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for anyone who may also need to know how to do this.

I implemented the phputf8 library, http://sourceforge.net/projects/phputf8/

I used the utf8_from_unicode function in utf8/utils/unicode.php

```
<?php
    // Example
    require_once 'utf8/utils/unicode.php';
    $key = 'U+3421';
    echo utf8_from_unicode(array(hexdec(substr($key,2))));
?>
```

Comment: consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the "tick" or "check" icon next to it